# How can i use butterknife in android studio?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, butterknife

I'm using android studio 3.5. I have a problem in using butterknife.

When I try to write `@BindView(...)` android studio does not autocomplete my code.

When I write the code manually the android studio shows me the error: **cannot resolve symbol @BindView**

help me please

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added the dependency, sync project again and try, if you've missed dependency try putting following in your app level build.gradle file under dependencies tag

```
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
```

After syncing you should be able to use @BindView within the class. If you still get some error feel free to discuss or you can visit them [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)